# expand/collapse all in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a bunch of content tabs which has expand collapse icon in each panel. Since it is so manual to close all expanded divs one by one, there is a expand all and collapse all button given to expand and collapse in one shot.

This is working as expected. But what extra I need to add in this is,

On page load I need `'collapse all'` button to have inactive class coz there is no divs expanded when page loads for the first time.

And when any div is expanded, the inactive class should be remove from the `'collapse all'` button and vice versa.

here is my code

```
//expand/collapse all
$('.expandall-icon').click(function(){
        $(this).addClass('expand-inactive');
        $('.collapseall-icon').removeClass('collapse-inactive')
        $('.inner-content').slideDown();
    });
    $('.collapseall-icon').click(function(){
        $(this).addClass('collapse-inactive');
        $('.expandall-icon').removeClass('expand-inactive');
        $('.inner-content').slideUp();
    });     

    //Collapse and expand data
    $('.inner-content').hide();
    $(".expand a").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().toggleClass('collapse');
        $(this).closest('.content').find('.inner-content').slideToggle();   
    });
```

And **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ALudAWE/4/)**

---

Tried with `if` `else` condition by adding `inactive` class by default but this doesnt remove the `inactive` class even though I am checking the condition of the expanded div.

```
    //expand/collapse all
$('.expandall-icon').click(function(){
        $(this).addClass('expand-inactive');
        $('.collapseall-icon').removeClass('collapse-inactive')
        $('.inner-content').slideDown();
    });
$('.collapseall-icon').addClass('collapse-inactive');
    $('.collapseall-icon').click(function(){
        $(this).addClass('collapse-inactive');
        $('.expandall-icon').removeClass('expand-inactive');
        $('.inner-content').slideUp();
    });     

    //Collapse and expand data
    $('.inner-content').hide();
    $(".expand a").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().toggleClass('collapse');
        $(this).closest('.content').find('.inner-content').slideToggle().toggleClass('datapanel_opend');    

      //expand all
         if(!$(this).closest('.content').find('.inner-content').hasClass("datapanel_opend"))
        {
           $('div.collapseall-icon').removeClass('collapse-inactive');
        }
        else
        {
            $('div.collapseall-icon').addClass('collapse-inactive');
        }

    });
```

**[DEMO 2](http://jsbin.com/aQiNEpEW/3/)**

Comment: Try to create a single button for expend-all and collapse-all, when any of the panel expends, change the name and functionality of the button to collapse-all and vise versa.

Comment: Can not create single button coz this is the requirement

Comment: See http://jsbin.com/ALudAWE/5/

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7xaUB/2/

Comment: @ArunPJohny Cool. looks like this is it.. Thank you. Let me try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made quite a few modifications in your code, so there might be a better way of doing this. Here's the code:

```
$('.collapseall-icon').addClass('collapse-inactive');

$('.expandall-icon').click(function () {
    $(this).addClass('expand-inactive');
    $('.collapseall-icon').removeClass('collapse-inactive')
    $('.inner-content').slideDown();
    $('.expand').removeClass('collapse');
});

$('.collapseall-icon').click(function () {
    $(this).addClass('collapse-inactive');
    $('.expandall-icon').removeClass('expand-inactive');
    $('.inner-content').slideUp();
    $('.expand').addClass('collapse');
});

$('.inner-content').hide();

$(".expand a").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('collapse');
    $(this).closest('.content').find('.inner-content').slideToggle();
    if ($('.collapse').length === $('.content').length) {
        $('.collapseall-icon').addClass('collapse-inactive');
        $('.expandall-icon').removeClass('expand-inactive');
    } else if ($('.collapse').length === 0) {
        $('.expandall-icon').addClass('expand-inactive');
        $('.collapseall-icon').removeClass('collapse-inactive');
    } else {
        $('.expandall-icon').removeClass('expand-inactive');
        $('.collapseall-icon').removeClass('collapse-inactive');
    }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ALudAWE/32/)

Comment: Is that `length === 2` is really requiered coz in my case there are n number of panels(dynamically), here i have shown only 2 for example

Comment: I have also written 2 for example :) You can replace 2 with `$('.content').length`. See http://jsbin.com/ALudAWE/32/

Answer (score 2):

Add the follwing code to your code.

```
var k = 0;
if(k == 0){
$('.collaspeall-icon').addClass('collapse-inactive');
$('.expandall-icon').removeClass('collapse-inactive');
k = 1;
}

if(k == 1){
$('.expandall-icon').addClass('collapse-inactive');
$('.collapseall-icon').removeClass('collapse-inactive');
k = 0;
}
```

alternative solution

```
$('.collapseall-icon').addClass('collapse-inactive');//added when page loads.


$('.expand').click(function(){

$('.collapseall-icon').removeClass('collapse-inactive');


});
```

Comment: Not working. I need to have inactive class by default to collapseall button and remove tat class when any one div is expanded.

Comment: In your answer both the links are still working as in my demo, only change is expandall link has inactive class.

Comment: Then add the class inactive when page loads. now when the user clicks any of the expand link remove active class and show the collapse link

Comment: I even tried that way, adding if else condition but this is not removing the inactive class when the div is opened. PLease check the demo here http://jsbin.com/aQiNEpEW/2/

Comment: so i have another code now please see the alternative solution here.

Comment: This works for the first click but when user close the expanded div manually by using the `collapse/expand` button provided in the div itself, then again the header `collapseall` button should have inactive state.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
//expand/collapse all
$('.expandall-icon').click(function () {
    $(this).addClass('expand-inactive');
    $('.collapseall-icon').removeClass('collapse-inactive')
    $('.inner-content').slideDown();
});
$('.collapseall-icon').click(function () {
    $(this).addClass('collapse-inactive');
    $('.expandall-icon').removeClass('expand-inactive');
    $('.inner-content').slideUp();
}).addClass('collapse-inactive');

//Collapse and expand data
var $inners = $('.inner-content').hide();
$(".expand a").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $parent = $(this).parent().toggleClass('collapse');
    if ($parent.hasClass('collapse')) {
        if ($('.expand').not('.collapse').length == 0) {
            $('.collapseall-icon').addClass('collapse-inactive')
        }
        $('.expandall-icon').removeClass('expand-inactive');
    } else {
        if ($('.expand.collapse').length == 0) {
            $('.expandall-icon').addClass('expand-inactive');
        }
        $('.collapseall-icon').removeClass('collapse-inactive')
    }
    $(this).closest('.content').find('.inner-content').slideToggle();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7xaUB/)

Answer (score -1):

EDITEDDDD
this is easy

```
$('.content .inner-content').slideToggle();
```

and you can use toggleClass if class `.collapse height:0px`

Answer (score -1):

Adding that `collapse-inactive` class on page load using this self executing function should work.

```
function(){
  $('.collapseall-icon').addClass('collapse-inactive');
}();
```